# magento development script vs production script oh head file

Tags: php, git, magento, production

I am new to magento and I am trying to add a script to the head of my document. I have a specific script for my development site and another one for my production site. How can i add the code that will be used for each one but not have it conflict with my version control?

I use git and i have a my development site on a subdomain.

thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I found a way in which you can do this I'm not sure this will fit to your requirement but you can try this

put the following code in your header.phtml

```html
<?php
if (isset($_SERVER['MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE'])) {
    // add script for development site
}else{
    // add script for production side 
}
?>
```

For your development side open their .htaccess file and put the following code at the end off file

```html
SetEnv MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE true
```

I hope this will help you out

Thanks